# Ionic3/Angular 4 Set Focus

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

Is there a "best" practice for setting focus either on page load or after an event.

I've tried the following but getting really inconsistent results with focus setting or not setting. I would need it to set focus to different types of inputs too (buttons, text, etc) either on load or after an event, etc.

I'm just looking to find if there is a solid way to set focus as to this point I haven't found a great way to accomplish this.

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    this.setFocusToInput('employeeIdInput');
  }

  setFocusToInput(inputName) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this[inputName].setFocus();
    }, 1000);  
  }
```

Comment: I think it's better to create a directive, inject an ElementRef, and use that to set focus on the element. Then you can reuse the directive as well

Comment: What you wrote should work. I would put it inside a service so that it would be reusable. I would also wrap it inside a `try-catch` block to handle the case that `this[inputName]` doesn't exist.